# Tkinter PhotoImage() not finding directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tkinter PhotoImage throws TclError 'no such file or directory' when the image path is correct (to the best of my knowledge)
[Error Thrown And Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBZ00.png)

[File Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqVmb.png)

I have tried using double/single quotes (though I'm not sure it matters), using '/' and '\', putting 'background.png' in the same directory as my code but to no avail.

I have a feeling I'm doing something stupid so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do / instead of \

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of code or error messages. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format it directly in your question.

Comment: Are you aware that relative paths are relative to the current working directory, which may not be the same as the directory where the script is?

Comment: @BryanOakley will do, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `./images/background.png` to make it a relative path.

`\images\background.png` would point to the file system or drive root.

Comment: Still throws the error with the path as ./images/background.png

Comment: Note that the path is relative to the current working directory, which may not be the same as where the script is located.

Comment: @BryanOakley The script is located in the same directory, V_Alpha_0.0.1, as the 'images' folder.

Comment: @Cam010: ok, but like I said, relative paths are relative to the _current working directory_. That is not necessarily the same as the path where the script is. They will only be the same thing if you `cd` to that directory before running the script.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks, I've looked up on it and the error is no longer thrown. It still doesn't load the image, but I've other theories for that.